# How to migrate rethinkdb server to another machine

Tags: rethinkdb

We plan to migrate rethinkdb serve to another machine(because hard disk of current machine is not enough).

> What's the preferred way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying over the `rethinkdb_data` directory should work fine as long as you're careful to shut down the old node before doing the copy, and to never have both nodes running at once.